# Как заставить .NET оптимизировать код?

Tags: c#, .net

Сравнивая производительность

```
public static int GetR(int argb)
{
    return (argb >> 16) & 0xff;
}
...
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
{
    temp1 = GetR(i);
}
```

и

```
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
{
    temp2 = (i >> 16) & 0xff;
}
```

Обнаружил, что первый способ работает чуть медленнее. По дизассемблированному коду studio видно, что метод не подставляется inline.
Неужели такие простые методы не делаются inline?
.Net 4.5 (интересует также для .Net 4.0 и желательно для 3.5, 2.0), компилирую в стандартной конфигурации Release VS2012.

Аналогично:

```
public static int BuildArgb(int alpha, int red, int green, int blue)
{
    return (red << 16) | (green << 8) | (blue << 0) | (alpha << 24);
}

... 
for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
{
    color = BuildArgb(aBytes[i], rBytes[i], gBytes[i], bBytes[i]);
}
```

и

```
for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
{
    color = (rBytes[i] << 16) | (gBytes[i] << 8) | (bBytes[i]) | (aBytes[i] << 24);
}
```

Можно ли попросить компилятор оптимизировать код ?

**UPD**
Код измерений для второго примера:

```
private static void Test3(int sz)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Test BuildArgb");

    Random random = new Random(255);
    byte[] aBytes = new byte[sz];
    byte[] rBytes = new byte[sz];
    byte[] gBytes = new byte[sz];
    byte[] bBytes = new byte[sz];
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
    {
        aBytes[i] = (byte)random.Next();
        rBytes[i] = (byte)random.Next();
        gBytes[i] = (byte)random.Next();
        bBytes[i] = (byte)random.Next();
    }

    int color = 0;

    var s2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
    {
        color = BuildArgb(aBytes[i], rBytes[i], gBytes[i], bBytes[i]);
    }

    s2.Stop();

    var s3 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
    {
        color = (rBytes[i] << 16) | (gBytes[i] << 8) | (bBytes[i] << 0) | (aBytes[i] << 24);
    }

    s3.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("BuildArgb: " + s2.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
    Console.WriteLine("Inline: " + s3.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
    Console.WriteLine(color);
}
```

**UOD 2**

Полный код примера 2

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    using System;

    using System.Diagnostics;

    internal class Program
    {
        public static int BuildArgb(int alpha, int red, int green, int blue)
        {
            return (red << 16) | (green << 8) | (blue << 0) | (alpha << 24);
        }

        private static void Main()
        {
            const int max = int.MaxValue;

            //Test1(max);
            //Test2(1024 * 1024 * 100);
            Test3(1024 * 1024 * 100);

            Console.Read();
        }           

        private static void Test3(int sz)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test BuildArgb");

            Random random = new Random(255);
            byte[] aBytes = new byte[sz];
            byte[] rBytes = new byte[sz];
            byte[] gBytes = new byte[sz];
            byte[] bBytes = new byte[sz];
            for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
            {
                aBytes[i] = (byte)random.Next();
                rBytes[i] = (byte)random.Next();
                gBytes[i] = (byte)random.Next();
                bBytes[i] = (byte)random.Next();
            }

            int color = 0;

            var s2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
            {
                color = BuildArgb(aBytes[i], rBytes[i], gBytes[i], bBytes[i]);
            }

            s2.Stop();

            var s3 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
            {
                color = (rBytes[i] << 16) | (gBytes[i] << 8) | (bBytes[i] << 0) | (aBytes[i] << 24);
            }

            s3.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("BuildArgb: " + s2.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
            Console.WriteLine("Inline: " + s3.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
            Console.WriteLine(color);  // Использование переменной, что бы циклы не скомпилировались пустыми
        }
    }
}
```

**UPD 3**
Тестовый код нужно подкорректировать, результат переменной `color` зависит только от второго цикла, что может повлечь оптимизации, которые повлияют на результаты тестов. После корректировки результат почти одинаковый - в пределах погрешности.

Comment: Проверьте, что вы (1) компилируете Release, (2) запускаете код **не** из-под отладчика. В обоих этих случаях набор оптимизаций сильно урезается для удобства отладки. (Вам придётся приаттачить отладчик после старта программы, и, возможно, после пробега jitter'ом нужной функции.)

Comment: Ваш результат (`color`) зависит лишь от _последней_ итерации цикла, поэтому оптимизатор вполне вправе выкинуть остальные итерации. Сделайте так, чтобы ответ зависел от промежуточных вычислений. Например, можно сложить их все.

Comment: @VladD спасибо за подсказку, действительно, не заметил, сейчас результат одинаковый.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Неужели такие простые методы не делаются inline?

Во втором примере JIT вполне успешно инлайнит метод при запуске в конфигурации Release не под отладкой. Более того, полученный нативный код практически совпадает для первого и второго вариантов, отличается лишь порядок применения сдвигов.

Это можно легко проверить:

- Дописать `Debugger.Launch();` где-то в теле `Test3`
- Выбрать конфигурацию `Release`
- Запустить не под отладчиком
- В появившемся окне выбрать уже открытых экземпляр студии
- Кликнуть правой кнопкой рядом с местом остановки, выбрать `Go To Disassembly`

Для второго случая результат примерно такой:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
{
    temp1 = GetR(i);
}
```

превратилось в

```
            for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
00E6055A  xor         eax,eax  
            for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
00E6055C  test        ebx,ebx  
00E6055E  jle         00E60570  
00E60560  mov         ecx,eax  
00E60562  sar         ecx,10h  
00E60565  and         ecx,0FFh  
00E6056B  inc         eax  
00E6056C  cmp         eax,ebx  
00E6056E  jl          00E60560  
            }
```

а второй цикл

```
for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
{
    temp2 = (i >> 16) & 0xff;
}
```

превратился в

```
            for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
00E60570  xor         eax,eax  
            for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
00E60572  test        ebx,ebx  
00E60574  jle         00E60586  
            {
                temp2 = (i >> 16) & 0xff;
00E60576  mov         edx,eax  
00E60578  sar         edx,10h  
00E6057B  and         edx,0FFh  
            for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
00E60581  inc         eax  
00E60582  cmp         eax,ebx  
00E60584  jl          00E60576  
            }
```

Как видно, результат полностью одинаковый - так что любая разница - это просто погрешность измерений.

Само интересное, что если `temp1` и `temp2` не используются после из расчета, то JIT просто выбрасывает сам расчет:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
0062054E  xor         eax,eax  
            for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
00620550  test        ebx,ebx  
00620552  jle         00620559  
00620554  inc         eax  
00620555  cmp         eax,ebx  
00620557  jl          00620554  
            }
```

Вы же используете `temp1` и `temp2` после тела цикла? Если нет - то вы просто измеряете скорость перемотки цикла.

Для второго примера картина та же - ассемблерный код практически совпадает, отличается лишь порядок применения сдвигов:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
xor         edx,edx  
test        ebx,ebx  
jle         00ED063E  
mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-28h]  
  {
      color = Argb32Helper.MakeArgb(aBytes[i], rBytes[i], gBytes[i], bBytes[i]);
mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-28h]  
cmp         edx,dword ptr [eax+4]  
jae         00ED077F  
movzx       eax,byte ptr [eax+edx+8]  
mov         dword ptr [ebp-24h],eax  
mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-2Ch]  
cmp         edx,dword ptr [eax+4]  
jae         00ED077F  
movzx       esi,byte ptr [eax+edx+8]  
mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-30h]  
cmp         edx,dword ptr [eax+4]  
jae         00ED077F  
movzx       ecx,byte ptr [eax+edx+8]  
mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-34h]  
cmp         edx,dword ptr [eax+4]  
jae         00ED077F  
movzx       edi,byte ptr [eax+edx+8]  
  {
      color = Argb32Helper.MakeArgb(aBytes[i], rBytes[i], gBytes[i], bBytes[i]);
mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-24h]  
shl         eax,10h  
shl         esi,8  
or          eax,esi  
or          eax,ecx  
shl         edi,18h  
or          eax,edi  
mov         dword ptr [ebp-10h],eax  
  for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
inc         edx  
cmp         edx,ebx  
jl          00ED05DD  
  }
```

`call` нет, метод заинлайнен.

для второго цикла:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
xor         ecx,ecx  
test        ebx,ebx  
jle         00ED06EB  
mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-2Ch]  
  {
      color = (rBytes[i] << 16) | (gBytes[i] << 8) | (bBytes[i] << 0) | (aBytes[i] << 24);
mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-2Ch]  
cmp         ecx,dword ptr [eax+4]  
jae         00ED077F  
movzx       eax,byte ptr [eax+ecx+8]  
shl         eax,10h  
mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-30h]  
cmp         ecx,dword ptr [edx+4]  
jae         00ED077F  
movzx       edx,byte ptr [edx+ecx+8]  
shl         edx,8  
or          eax,edx  
mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-34h]  
cmp         ecx,dword ptr [edx+4]  
jae         00ED077F  
movzx       edx,byte ptr [edx+ecx+8]  
or          eax,edx  
mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-28h]  
cmp         ecx,dword ptr [edx+4]  
jae         00ED077F  
movzx       edx,byte ptr [edx+ecx+8]  
shl         edx,18h  
or          eax,edx  
mov         dword ptr [ebp-10h],eax  
  for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
inc         ecx  
cmp         ecx,ebx  
jl          00ED0690  
  }
```

Разница в выполнении чуть заметна, и зависит от порядка вызова циклов - тот, что вызывается первым, всегда немного медленее - именно поэтому в тестах всегда надо делать разогрев.

Бонус: для совсем нового JIT из 4.6 на моей машине код совпадает еще больше - тело цикла будет состоит из 4-х блоков вида

```
mov         eax,dword ptr [rbx+8]  
cmp         ecx,eax  
jae         00007FF805D207F8  
movsxd      rax,ecx  
movzx       eax,byte ptr [rbx+rax+10h]
```

и отличается только порядком блоков.

первая проверка - `mov/cmp/jae` - это проверка выхода за границы массива. Формально она выполняется в цикле 4 раза, что должно добавлять тормозов. Но на практике этот переход очень хорошо предсказывается современными процессорами. Так что практически цикл просто читает данные из массивов и пишет их в соответствующие байты результата.

Comment: Да, `tem1` и `tem2` использую, что бы цикл не скомпилировался пустым. А во втором случаи, с методом с 4-я аргументами такой же результат?

Comment: @dev0547 да, там тоже будет инлайн. я приводил код в первой ревизии - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/424556/revisions - но там полотно, решил оставить вариант покороче. Сейчас верну.

Comment: @dev0547 вообще вариант сильно зависит от машины (версии дотнета) и от битности. так что лучше проверяйте у себя локально. но инлайн точно будет.

Comment: @ PashaPash проверил по вашему методу, все верно, метод встраивается. У меня была небольшая неточность в тестах, что влекло небольшую разницу, UPD 3 вопроса.

Answer (score 7):

*Заставить* не получится. Если вы хотите указать компилятору чтобы он *по возможности* заинлайнл вызов метода, используйте атрибут

`[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]`

Работает с версии 4.5.

Вот тут более подробно: [Aggressive Inlining in the CLR 4.5 JIT](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2012/01/20/aggressive-inlining-in-the-clr-45-jit/).

UPD.

> По дизассемблированному коду studio видно, что метод не подставляется inline.

Проверять это рефлектором бесполезно. Данная оптимизация происходит на этапе JIT, который преобразует промежуточный язык .NET в машинный код.

Comment: Да, но это только для 4.5. Читал, что предыдущие версии компиляторов тоже по своему усмотрению могут inline делать. Если такой простой метод не делается инлайн, то какие метода делаются инлайн?  Можете дать оценку производительности 2-х выше указанных методов?  По моим тестам первый пример показывает почти такую же скорость, а второй - производительность упала на 17%. - это потому, что во втором примере 4 аргумента и на их передачу тратится много времени, а в первом один аргумент и это не оказывает влияния на произв.?

Comment: Специально собрал проверочную программку по вашему коду. Разница в производительности между функцией и ручным переносом кода в цикл **на уровне погрешности**.

Comment: в первом случаи да, а во втором (с 4-я аргументами)?

Comment: Я второй случай проверял

Comment: может мои измерения некорректны? Обновил вопрос. Для sz = 1024 * 1024 * 100 у меня стабильно получаются результаты 285,4184 и 241,5105.   
  
> Проверять это рефлектором бесполезно. Данная оптимизация происходит на этапе JIT, который преобразует промежуточный язык .NET в машинный код.   
- подозревал об этом, поэтому делал измерения

Comment: @dev0547: если вы измеряете из-под Visual Studio, результат будет неправильный. Измеряйте без него.

Comment: @VladD да, я запускаю .exe файл

Comment: @dev0547 приведите полный код примера, чтобы было понятно что именно вы меряете. потому что одной строчкой  `Console.WriteLine(temp2)` в самом конце кода можно "замедлить" соответствующий цикл в полтора раза.

Comment: @PashaPash обновил, UPD 2

Comment: @dev0547 ваш код выдает у меня результаты с разницей в тик-два, особенно если сделать разогрев - несколько вызовов `Test3(1024 * 1024 * 100);` На первом вызове первый цикл будет чуть медленее - на пару миллисекунд - поэтому нельзя мерять без разогрева.

Comment: @dev0547 mantigatos вам уже писал выше - разница на уровне погрешности.